# Refresh Token Flow With Authorization Code Flow

Tags: oauth-2.0, refresh-token, openiddict

Is there a **OpenIddict** Sample with **Authorization Code Flow** with **Refresh Token**s?

I use Velusia sample project as server and add

```
options.AllowRefreshTokenFlow();
```

to my .AddServer function. I add "**offline_access**" scope to my Application. However when I send Authorization code to the server, it doesn't return a refresh token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to add **offline_access** scope to my client code request. When I add it, everything worked as expected.